# Do deathtouch and deathtouch-like effects stop trample damage?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

My friend has a trample deck, and I have a [Stinkweed Imp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Stinkweed%20Imp) that says "Whenever Stinkweed Imp deals combat damage to a creature, destroy that creature."  Can a creature destroyed this way still deal trample damage?

What if I block with a creature that actually has deathtouch?

Answer (score 11):

Yes, a creature destroyed by Stinkweed Imp will still deal trample damage. Basically, the sequence of actions in combat goes like this:

1. Your opponent attacks with their creature that has trample.
2. You block that creature with your Stinkweed Imp.
3. All damage is resolved. This includes the damage dealt to and by Stinkweed Imp, and the trample damage to you. Because Stinkweed Imp dealt damage to a creature, its triggered ability goes on the stack.
4. If there is 2 damage marked on Stinkweed Imp, it dies. Then your opponent gains priority with the triggered ability on the stack.
5. The triggered ability resolves, and the creature with trample dies.

If you replace Stinkweed Imp with a creature with deathtouch ([Deadly Recluse](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Deadly%20Recluse), for example), steps 3, 4, and 5 are replaced with this:

3. All damage is resolved. This includes the damage dealt to and by Deadly Recluse, and the trample damage to you. Because the creature with trample took damage from Deadly Recluse, it dies, no matter what it's toughness is (see [rule 704.5h](http://mtgsalvation.gamepedia.com/State-based_actions)

Comment: Could be useful to note that the trigger is when Stinkweed Imp deals combat damage, and isn't simply a blocking trigger like Engulfing Slagwurm.

Comment: I did say that it happens when damage happens, and not when blockers are declared.

Comment: Minor thing: it might be useful to be clear that Stinkweed Imp dies before the opponent gets priority. It doesn't matter for this case, of course, but I could imagine that it might throw off a new player reading this sometime in the future.

Comment: I fixed it. But they basically happen at the same time, so I don't really think it matters.

Comment: A question about just deathtouch (not pseudo-deathtouch) got duped against this one, so I edited the question to ask about actual deathtouch in the body not just the title; maybe worth making it more prominent in the answer too?

Comment: OK, I've expanded the part about deathtouch

Answer (score 8):

Combat damage is dealt all at once, and so a creature destroyed by or in response to combat damage will still deal all of its damage, including any trample damage.

> 510.2. Second, **all combat damage that’s been assigned is dealt simultaneously**. This turn-based action doesn’t use the stack. No player has the chance to cast spells or activate abilities between the time combat damage is assigned and the time it’s dealt. This is a change from previous rules.